# Android app never starts

Tags: android

I am trying to run my android app in the "Android Developer Tools Build: v21.0.0-519525" for mac osx. The emulator starts fine but just keeps looking like this:

[image]

Yesterday it worked just fine. I have tried to close ADT and run:

```
>adb kill-server
>adb start-server
```

as described here:

[Android app not launching on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203581/android-app-not-launching-on-emulator)

are there any temporaries that needs to be deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the emulator off the screenlock by swiping the lock from left to right first before starting the app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unlock the emulator screen by swiping the lock toward right. Then your app will show up