# Android app is not launching in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

When I am trying to launch an app in the emulator through Eclipse, the app is not launching and I am not getting any error also.

WHen I check in the target section of project properties, I can't see any AVD in the list even though I created a new AVD and it is running.

Comment: Similar question has been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203581/android-app-not-launching-on-emulator

Comment: Close eclipse.. go to command prompt, run adb devices and check whether you are able to see the devices, if not run adb kill-server and adb start-server. start eclipse again.. by the way why are you using eclipse?? try android studio.

Comment: When I set the activity to my application main activity, I am ale to see the AVD in the list.But still it is not loading the app on emulator.

Comment: In the COnsole, the below text is visible at end.


[2015-08-19 13:39:28 - A] Uploading A.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-08-19 13:39:38 - A] Installing A.apk...
[2015-08-19 13:41:00 - A] Success!
[2015-08-19 13:41:01 - A] Starting activity com.example.a.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

Comment: Eventhough it is showing as starting but it is not opening.I waited so much time but no use.So I unlocked the screen of emulator and my app is visible there, so I clicked on it but it is showing as "Unfortunately launcher has stopped".

Answer (score 1):

Your android emulator might fails to connect **eclipse DDMS** tool and ask for `adb to start manually`. In that case you can start or stop the adb using the command prompt.So, I recommend running in a single command line:

```
sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
```

If not works please switch To [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) .Eclipse is dead .